# Tumblr Photo Caption within Container

Tags: photo, tumblr, caption

I have a blog theme which does not include captions in photo posts. I have been successful with plugging in `{block:Caption} {Caption} {/block:Caption}` before `{/block:Photo}`, but the caption seems to be floating on the background and not inside the post box as seen below:

[image]

How do I include the caption to be apart of the same box as the date?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if you posted the relevant code here. I don't know what theme you are using but if you take a look at this site http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes you'll see that dates are rendered by {block:Date} {/block:Date}, {Timestamp}, {DayOfYear} etc. Take a look and see which one suits you theme. When you have found it, simply Ctrl + F in you code and find where in your HTML code the date box is rendered and then put the {block:Caption} {Caption} {/block:Caption} inside.